# Dynamic parcelable createTypedArrayList

Tags: java, android, dynamic, parcelable

I'm trying to make a function to make parcelable classes dynamically. But when I reach an ArrayList I can do `dest.writeTypedList()` buen when reading it if the array is null it gives me an exception that says

```
android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling.
```

The line that dies is this one.

```
in.createTypedArrayList((Parcelable.Creator<? extends Object>) mClass.getDeclaredField("CREATOR").get(targetClass));
```

This is the part of my method that runs when the field to read is an ArrayList:

```
try {
                    String fieldNameUpperCase = field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.getName().substring(1);
                    Method methodCall = targetClass.getClass().getMethod("set" + fieldNameUpperCase, field.getType());
                    String className = ((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0].toString();
                    className = className.substring(className.indexOf(" ") + 1);
                    Class mClass = Class.forName(className);
                    methodCall.invoke(targetClass, new ArrayList<PhoneByProducer>());
                    List<PhoneByProducer> lstPhones = new ArrayList<>();
                    in.readList(lstPhones, mClass.getClassLoader());
                    methodCall.invoke(targetClass, lstPhones);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This is my class:

```
public class ParcelableGenerator {

private static List<Field> lstFields;

public static void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags, Object origin) {
    lstFields = new ArrayList<>();
    Class actualClass = origin.getClass();
    while (actualClass != null && actualClass.getSuperclass() != null) {
        Field[] fields = actualClass.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (Parcelable.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                try {
                    String fieldNameUpperCase = field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.getName().substring(1);
                    dest.writeParcelable((Parcelable) origin.getClass().getMethod("get" + fieldNameUpperCase).invoke(origin), flags);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                try {
                    String fieldNameUpperCase = field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.getName().substring(1);
                    dest.writeList((List<Parcelable>) origin.getClass().getMethod("get" + fieldNameUpperCase).invoke(origin));
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                try {
                    String fieldNameUpperCase = field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.getName().substring(1);
                    dest.writeByte(((boolean) origin.getClass().getMethod("is" + fieldNameUpperCase).invoke(origin)) ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    Method method = dest.getClass().getMethod("write" + field.getType().getSimpleName(), field.getType());
                    String fieldNameUpperCase = field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.getName().substring(1);
                    method.invoke(dest, origin.getClass().getMethod("get" + fieldNameUpperCase).invoke(origin));
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        actualClass = actualClass.getSuperclass();
    }
}

public static void readFromParcel(Parcel in, Object targetClass) {
    Class actualClass = targetClass.getClass();
    while (actualClass != null && actualClass.getSuperclass() != null) {
        Field[] fields = actualClass.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (Parcelable.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                try {
                    String fieldNameUpperCase = field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.getName().substring(1);
                    Method methodCall = targetClass.getClass().getMethod("set" + fieldNameUpperCase, field.getType());
                    Log.d("debuglog - read", fieldNameUpperCase);
                    Object obj = in.readParcelable(field.getType().getClassLoader());
                    methodCall.invoke(targetClass, obj);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                try {
                    String fieldNameUpperCase = field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.getName().substring(1);
                    Method methodCall = targetClass.getClass().getMethod("set" + fieldNameUpperCase, field.getType());
                    String className = ((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0].toString();
                    className = className.substring(className.indexOf(" ") + 1);
                    Class mClass = Class.forName(className);
                    methodCall.invoke(targetClass, new ArrayList<PhoneByProducer>());
                    List<PhoneByProducer> lstPhones = new ArrayList<>();
                    in.readList(lstPhones, mClass.getClassLoader());
                    methodCall.invoke(targetClass, lstPhones);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                try {
                    String fieldNameUpperCase = field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.getName().substring(1);
                    Method methodCall = targetClass.getClass().getMethod("set" + fieldNameUpperCase, field.getType());
                    methodCall.invoke(targetClass, in.readByte() != 0);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    String fieldNameUpperCase = field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.getName().substring(1);
                    Method methodCall = targetClass.getClass().getMethod("set" + fieldNameUpperCase, field.getType());
                    Method method = in.getClass().getMethod("read" + field.getType().getSimpleName());
                    methodCall.invoke(targetClass, method.invoke(in));
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        actualClass = actualClass.getSuperclass();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: why are you using `mClass.getDeclaredField("CREATOR").get(targetClass)` and not `PhoneByProducer.CREATOR` directly?

Comment: Because im trying to make a dynamic parcel. Instead of maken each line for each field of each class that implements Parcelable, I'm just implementing my own parcel generator class like this:
    ParcelableGenerator.writeToParcel(dest, flags, origin);

I'm checking every Field that mi Entity has.

That typeCast is just for testing. I sohudlnt use that TypeCast

Comment: I've just editet the question and delete the typecasting. that should return a an ArrayList<Object> depending on the field

Comment: i have no idea what you mean but you could take a look into sources of `Parcel#readParcelableCreator` method

Comment: Maybe if I show you my entire class. check the question again plz.

Comment: what is the reason for `readFromParcel` method? typically if you are writing `class MyParcelable implements Parcelable` you are creating `private MyParcelable(Parcel in)` constructor so this is exactly what you want to achieve... or am i missing something? see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for a typical `MyParcelable` class